# Can I build a Chrome extension that updates an excel Office Online document

Tags: javascript, excel, google-chrome-extension, office-addins, office-online-server

I am trying to figure out the best way to automate the gathering and exporting of information from a site I am visiting regularly to a excel sheet. I need to be able to both scrape information from the site as well as input some manually, which is why I thought a chrome extension would be a good idea.

I know that you cannot write to local files from a chrome extension, but I am trying to figure out if I can write to office online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah  actually i was working on something like this a month ago but not an extension just a google form that sends the data to google sheets when you submit and you can do that in an extension fo sho lemme send you the link to the youtube video i saw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7ZwbTW3LF4&ab_channel=SheetDB
If your not pleased with this video i saw alot look up
"saving form data to google sheets" on youtube :)
NOTE: I know you said excel sheet but google sheets work just as well and you can download them as a file and they have just as much functionality as excel - NOTE THAT I DONT THINK ITS POSSIBLE TO DO WITH EXCEL DUE TO SAFETY PROTOCALS, NO EXTENSION CAN WRITE TO FILES ON YOUR COMPUTER SINCE THATS JUST NOT SAFE - but my alternative is the next best thing if not better :D

Comment: Thankyou I think you are right about the google sheets being the best option. Thankyou for taking the time to answer.